# jQuery file validation with formvalidator plugin is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to validate input file type with formvalidator.net plugin
but the errors is not showing, what is the wrong in the below code?
and its working fine for other type of input.
here is example of what iam doing:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
        $.validate({
            form : '#form',
            modules : 'file'
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<form id="form">
    <input type="file" name="images"
           data-validation="mime size"
           data-validation-allowing="jpg, png, gif"
           data-validation-max-size="512kb"
           data-validation-error-msg-size="You can not upload images larger than 512kb"
           data-validation-error-msg-mime="You can only upload images"
    />
</form>
```

if this plugin will not work then what is the best plugin for form validation?

Comment: Your code is working fine in the fiddle. What is the issue?

Comment: can you share link of the test fiddle you made please

Comment: Check fiddle in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle below. I just used your code and it is giving the validation messages as expected.

```js
(function($){
    $.validate({
        form : '#form',
        modules : 'file'
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
    <input type="file" name="images"
           data-validation="mime size"
           data-validation-allowing="jpg, png, gif"
           data-validation-max-size="512kb"
           data-validation-error-msg-size="You can not upload images larger than 512kb"
           data-validation-error-msg-mime="You can only upload images"
    />
</form>
```

Comment: Thats strange, yes its working in fiddle, but when i copy same code in HTML in my desktop its not working and not showing any error

Comment: Are you using the same "jquery" and "jquery-form-validator" versions on your page? And are you loading the resources incorrect order? Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: In my previous comment, consider "incorrect" as "in correct".